# Android Gradle taking too much time for staring even new default blank activity

Tags: android, maven, android-studio

After Installing a very fresh install of android studio i continuously facing the same problem , gradle takes too much time for managing the dependencies, my internet connection is good, i have already replaced   jcenter() =>  maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' } , several time restart my system but nothing helps me in this situation , what the actual problem is?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

finally guys i found the problem , my antivirus program was responsible for that.